# Laravel Project on EC2 instance showing either directory structure or Error 404

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have set up an EC2 instance with Ubuntu v. 20.04.1 LTS. I have cloned an existing Laravel project from Gitlab that runs absolutely fine on local WAMP.

I need some help with the Apache Virtual Host and .htaccess configuration because depending on what I try, I either get the directory structure or a good old 404 error.

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/demo/public
    <Directory "/var/www/html/demo/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**/var/www/html/demo/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/html/demo/public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried all the usual variations of these. With the particular configuration given above, I get an Error 404.

I have enabled the rewrite mod so that's not the issue.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

By default, config in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` is not enabled or will be ignored. You will need to set enable to create symlink to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Try to run this command:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default
sudo a2ensite 000-default
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

But I think it's better to [define domain/virtual host](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) instead of use 000-default

Comment: I tried both.. used the default and defined another. And yes, I remembered to enable them as well